# How do I render partial via ajax in rails3 and jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I could do sth like this in rails 2:

```
def show_rec_horses
  rec_horses = Horses.find(:all)
  page["allHorses"].replace_html :partial => "horses/recommended", :locals => 
 {:rec_horses => rec_horses}
end
```

How do I do this in Rails3 with jQuery. So how can I replace html of my div with a partial via ajax call(link_to :remote => true) in Rails3.

I tried sth like (in my show_rec_horses.js.erb):

```
$("#interactionContainer").update("<%= escape_javascript(render("horses/recommended"))%>");
```

And nothing happens. I tried some other variations but none worked. What am doing wrong? Should this be approached in some other way? Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Okay, let's start with the controller.

```
def show_rec_horses
  @rec_horses = Horses.find(:all)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show_rec_horses.html.erb
    format.js   # show_rec_horses.js.erb
  end
end
```

This will make sure the correct templates are being rendered for either a html request or a javascript request. If you just need to respond to a javascript request, delete the html part.

Now let's say you have a page containing the following:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Show Horses', show_rec_horses_path, remote: true %></p>

<div id="interactionContainer"></div>
```

Clicking the link will make a request to the show_rec_horses action in your controller, this action will render the javascript file `show_rec_horses.js.erb`.

This javascript file should contain something like this:

```
$('#interactionContainer').html('<%=j render partial: 'horses/reccommended', locals: { rec_horses: @rec_horses } %>')
```

Now your container will be filled with the content of `horses/_reccommended.html.erb`, which for example could contain:

```
<% rec_horses.all.each do |rec_horse| %>
  <p><%= rec_horse.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me until I removed the "respond_to do |format|" block

Comment: Seems to work as i need but after removing format.html ajax request fails and go to error part. which should go 'show_rec_horses.js.erb', May be its because of rails 4 but not working for me.

Comment: This was helpful to me once I got past one thing: I forgot that I needed a route for show_rec_horses. This part is probably not here because it's obvious to most people familiar with Rails, but it might help to include it for others.