# Adding UI elements via partial when user clicks a button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to render a partial each time a button is clicked. This is for an event planning app, and everytime user clicks button, I want to add UI (via the partial) to a div where each instance of the UI has a datepicker, and start time/end time picker.

I have a button in a view "Add Date":

```
<%= submit_tag "Add Date", :type => 'button', class: "add_date_button"%>
```

Below the button I have an initially empty div:

```
<div class="dates_container">
```

On that same page I have Javascript (JQuery) to register a click handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.add_date_button').click(on_add_date);
</script>
```

In a separate file I have the click handler:

```
function on_add_date(){
  alert('here');
}
```

The click handler works, because the alert displays when the button is clicked.

I want to render a partial each time a button is clicked. This is for an event planning app, and everytime user clicks button, I want to add UI (via the partial) to a div where each instance of the UI has a datepicker, and start time/end time picker.

But with my noob understanding of Rails, by the time the user clicks the button, Rails has already rendered the page and sent it to the user's browser, so can't add UI via partial. Am I wrong on this?

Should I instead just use JQuery to add date/time creation UI lines to the div, and then when the form is saved the total date/time info is sent to backend? I can't have a page refresh, because user has entered other info in form and I can't wipe it out.

Comment: I once answered a similar question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099182/how-do-i-render-partial-via-ajax-in-rails3-and-jquery/16191404#16191404

Comment: I'm thinking this might be achieved through nested attributes, such as in this RailsCast with Ryan Bates:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Will that work for my situation, and is it the best practice way to do it?