# Update view with Rails (Ajax)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have an app of reservations. The thing is that admins can view reservations by date. This is done by an input with has appended datepicker. Each time the user picks a date, the view is updated (that's the idea). However, until now I don't know how to update the view with the new data. This are my methods:

```
def index
    @reserva = Reserva.new
    @reservas = Reserva.all.joins(:user).where.not(:user_id => session[:user_id])
    @mis_reservas = Reserva.where(:user_id => session[:user_id])
end

def actualizar_por_fecha
    if params[:fecha] != nil
        @mis_reservas = Reserva.find_by_fecha(params[:fecha])
        @reservas = Reserva.find_by_fecha(params[:fecha])
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render 'reservas/index' }
        end
    end
end
```

And the CoffeeScript code is the following:

```
$("input#ver_reservas_fecha").on "change", (e) ->
$.ajax
    url: "actualizar_lista_de_reservas_por_fecha"
    data:
      fecha: $("#ver_reservas_fecha").val()
    success: (data) ->
      console.log(data)
      return
  return
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that the real indentation in your CoffeeScript?

Comment: can you post the view code?

Comment: Use partials and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this question to know how to create a partial and refresh the div after ajax call.

[How do I render partial via ajax in rails3 and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099182/how-do-i-render-partial-via-ajax-in-rails3-and-jquery)

Also refer to this to understand it a bit more

http://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails